# Using while loop with SQL Query and Pandas

Tags: python, mysql, sql, pandas, while-loop

I am running a SQL query in python and storing the results of the table in a Pandas DataFrame. I'd like run the query until a condition in met. Here's some sample data to work with:

```
sql table1

name      val       
post      10
sutter    15
oak       20

import pandas as pd
# mysql connection
import pymysql
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
user = 'user1'
pwd = 'pwd'
host =  'xxxx.1.rds.amazonaws.com'
port = 3306
database = 'db1'
engine = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://{}:{}@{}/{}".format(user,pwd,host,database))


# Readdata
con = engine.connect()

v = 12

query = '''
        SELECT *
        FROM table1
        WHERE val < {}
        '''.format(v)

df = pd.read_sql(query, con)
```

I'd like to run this query until a condition is met. Condition is the size of the dataframe or number of rows returned. Above query returns `1` row. I need the query to update the value of `v` until the condition is satisfied. So, a `while-loop` would work.

```
While df.shape[0] => 2:

   run query
```

How do I run the query in a `while-loop` and check of # of rows returned or size of the dataframe?

Comment: If the condition is simply the # of rows returned then there's absolutely no need for the while condition. ORDER BY VAL and then SELECT TOP N rows. Or you can modify that slightly to return more rows if you want all rows tied for the val that sets you over the N threshold

Comment: The condition is # of rows, but there are a couple of caveats and `while-loop` would be ideal implementation. I have simplified for SO post. Could you recommend how I can do this within a `while loop`?

Comment: if you really need loop then maybe use `while True:`, next get data, next use `if` to check number of rows and use `break` to exit loop, and use `v += 1` to run loop with bigger value.

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to do it with loop then maybe use `while True:`, next get data, next use `if` to check number of rows and use `break` to exit loop, and use `v += 1` to run loop with bigger value

Something like

```
v = 12

query = '''
        SELECT *
        FROM table1
        WHERE val < {}
        '''

while True:

    df = pd.read_sql(query.format(v), con)

    if df.shape[0] >= 2:
        break

    v += 1
```

but if there is only one row in database then it may work forever and it may need other condition to stop it. ie. `while v < 10000:`

Comment: can you explain how `while True` works? Does it execute until it hits the `break` statement?

Comment: `while True` is endless loop - it runs forever - and `break` can exit it. It is popular method when you have to run some function in loop before you check its result.